Converting a single to double sum in The Art of Problem Solving, Volume 2
In Exercise 16-13 of The Art of Problem Solving, Volume 2 (p. 188), the authors convert a single sum to a double sum as follows:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{3^{n+1}} = \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=n}^\infty \frac{1}{3^m}.
$$
The text says, “Make sure you see the clever way in which the double sum is equal to the single sum!”, but I don't see it, and unfortunately the solutions manual is silent on the subject (and so is the Web as far as I can tell). Could someone explain where the double sum comes from?

Write $n$ as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}1$ and switch the sums.

Thanks. I considered something like this, but absolute convergence has not been discussed at this point in the book, so I expected a solution that didn’t require switching the order of summation.
